# Error Message when Running Global Morans with Spatial Weights Matrix

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, autocorrelation

I am attempting to run a global Moran's I test with a spatial weights matrix, however when I run the process I always receive an error message and I was hoping someone could point out when I am going wrong.

My project is looking at spatial autocorrelation of health in London, as part of the process was looking to produce a spatial weights matrix using Queen's method and K nearest neighbors in order to produce a global Moran's statistic using the matrix. However I always receive the error message attached.

How do I need to set up the spatial weights matrix to avoid these errors?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your error message occurs during HTML report creation phase, and more specifically, one or more values sent to this HTML report creator have `None`s which cannot be decoded to UTF-8. Most probably this is a bug that you need to raise with ESRI eventually.

I am not sure how important for you having this HTML report is but if you unchecked `Generate Report` option, you would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this question is still relevant, but I might as well share my solution.
I was having exactly the same problem. My layer of interest for Moran's I was a feature class in my geodatabase. Oddly enough, Global Moran's I tool was finally able to generate .html report file when the geodatabase was under edit session AND the layer was enabled in ArcMap's table of contents.

EDIT: I also found out that running Moran's I with spatial modeler also solves the problem